# Get-Aduser -Filter Option -notlike does not work

Tags: powershell

Attempting to use `Get-Aduser` to find entries in Active directory that are not in a text file.  The `-like` option appears to work but cannot seem to get the `-notlike` to work.
When I use the `-nolike` option, the entries in the text file appear as part of the output file. Using the `-like` option the powershell works.

Here is the contents of the text file

```
svcXXSQL001Agent
svcXXSQL001DBEng
svcXXSQL001Int
svcXXSQLUAT501DBEng
svcxxapp211
```

Here is my existing code:

```
$server=get-content C:\temp\test.txt
 foreach ($name in $server) {
 Get-ADUser -SearchBase “OU=ServiceAccts,DC=nlong,DC=com”  -Filter "name -notlike '$name'"  | sort | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "svcxxsql*"} | Select-    Object Name | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\foo.txt
 }
```

Thanks for the input, Norm.

Comment: Strip your code right back to basics... too many additional bits of "pipe-work" (get it `;-)`) going on there. Do you get any results of the simple `Get-AdUser` call with your `-notlike` filter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Expecting the output without the given names is a false assumption, let me demonstrate using the numbers 1 and 2, and the `Where-Object` cmdlet in place of the `Get-ADUser` filter all numbers from 1 to 5 *except* for `1` or `2`:

```
$numbers = 1,2,3
foreach($number in $numbers){
    # Let's output all numbers from 1 to 3, except for $number
    1..3 |Where-Object {$_ -notlike $number}
}
```

You will find the output to be:

```
2
3
1
3
1
2
```

In the first iteration of the loop, we receive the number `2` along with the number `3` - this is obviously not our intention, they were supposed to be filtered, but it ended up in the output because we filter only against 1 number at a time.

We can use either the `-notcontains` or `-notin` operators to filter against a collection of terms instead:

```
$numbers = 1,2,3
1..3 |Where-Object {$numbers -notcontains $_}
# or
1..3 |Where-Object {$_ -notin $numbers}
```

In your example, you would have to retrieve all the AD users and filter using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=ServiceAccts,DC=nlong,DC=com" |Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $server}  | sort | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "svcxxsql*"} | Select-Object Name | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\foo.txt
```

Since you're only interested in accounts that start with `svcxxsql`, we might as well place that as the filter:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=ServiceAccts,DC=nlong,DC=com" -Filter {Name -like "svcxxsql*"} |Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $server}  | sort | Select-Object Name | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\foo.txt
```

Comment: Here is the code I’m working with:

$server=get-content C:\temp\test.txt
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=ServiceAccts,DC=nlong,DC=com" -Filter {Name -like "svcfwsql*"} |Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $server}  | sort | Select-Object Name | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\foo.txt
Here are the contents of test.txt:
svcFWSQL001Agent
svcFWSQL001DBEng
svcFWSQL001Int
svcFWSQL002Agent       
svcFWSQL002Eng         
svcFWSQL002Int
When running the code with test.txt here is output in foo.txt:
Name                   
----                   
svcFWSQL002Agent       
svcFWSQL002Eng

Comment: As you can see the svcFWSQL001Agent, svcFWSQL001DBEng and svcFWSQL001Int are not there, which is a good.  However, svcFWSQL002Agent and svcFWSQL002Eng are still in foo.txt, they should not be there.

Comment: Now if I change the contents of test.txt to the following:
svcFWSQL001Agent
svcFWSQL001DBEng
svcFWSQL001Int

And re-runGet-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=ServiceAccts,DC=nlong,DC=com" -Filter {Name -like "svcfwsql*"} |Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $server}  | sort | Select-Object Name | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\foo.txt

The output in foo.txt is correct the FWSQL001 entries have been removed, the first entries in the file are fwsql002Agent, Eng and Int, 

Name                   
----                   
svcFWSQL002Agent       
svcFWSQL002Eng         
svcFWSQL002Int

Comment: Something is amiss, having more than three entries in test.txt is causing shall we say opportunities which I’m not smart enough to understand.

Thanks for your input.

Norm

Answer (score 0):

While this is old, here's a more efficient method using an actual LDAP filter that you construct from information supplied in the file.

Assuming the file contains the actual sAMAccountNames you wish to exclude:

```
$servers = get-content C:\temp\test.txt

# Begin the  filter - sAMAccountType=805306368 is user objects only, no contacts
$filter = '(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(!(|'
# recursively append each samAccountName to exclude in the filter
foreach ($u in $servers) {
    $filter = $filter + "(samAccountName=$u)"
}
#finish the filter
$filter = $filter + ')))'

#ldap filter looks like this
# (&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(!(|(samAccountName=svcXXSQL001Agent)(samAccountName=svcXXSQL001DBEng)(samAccountName=svcXXSQL001Int)(...))))

# run the query
Get-aduser -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase "OU=ServiceAccts,DC=nlong,DC=com"
```

Active Directory can technically take an LDAP query that's 10MB in size, although obviously that'd be really excessive. So I recommend the above method be used only if it's a limited number of items you want to exclude.

I use a similar method to build a query for users that are members of certain groups but not others, and for that, it's significantly faster than grabbing groups with thousands of users each and trying to compare members that are exclusive to one.

As always, test and compare the time to execute the different methods:

- grabbing everything and discarding unwanted results after
- grabbing a partially-filtered set and discarding after (like the original answer)
- constructing a more complex targeted query (this example)

Also consider that processing loads occur in different places. It can take a long time for a DC to execute a very long, complex LDAP query, with extra CPU and potential timeouts. But it can take even longer to grab all the properties from every single object from AD, with potential connection timeouts, with more data travelling across the wire to the target system, then getting all that data processed locally.

In my experience, it's the "grab everything" queries with big result sets that cause the most load, on DCs, network and target systems (Perfmon LDAP monitoring on the DCs can be *interesting*). That's that's why it's often best for the DC to do the filtering work, as long as the LDAP filters are sensible.